# Split Vector into Vector of Vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

I am currently working with a text file of results from Yelp containing restaurants and some other information. Each element for a restaurant is separated by a vertical line (|) and each restaurant is separated by a new line (\n). (See example below). I am trying to split this line into a vector of vectors. The larger vector would hold all smaller vectors, while the smaller vectors would each hold the information for one of the restaurants. How do I best approach this?

Here are a couple lines from the file:

```
Meka's Lounge|42.74|-73.69|407 River Street+Troy, NY 12180|http ://www.yelp.com/biz/mekas-lounge-troy|Bars|5|2|4|4|3|4|5
Tosca Grille|42.73|-73.69|200 Broadway+Troy, NY 12180|http ://www.yelp.com/biz/tosca-grille-troy|American (New)|1|3|2|4
Happy Lunch|42.75|-73.68|827 River St+Troy, NY 12180|http ://www.yelp.com/biz/happy-lunch-troy|American (Traditional)|5|2
Hoosick Street Discount Beverage Center|42.74|-73.67|2200 19th St+Troy, NY 12180|http ://www.yelp.com/biz/hoosick-street-discount-beverage-center-troy|Beer, Wine & Spirits|4|5|5|5|5|4
```

Comment: The best way to approach this would be to write some code.

Comment: @mbgda -- I have some code written. It's not working, so now I'm here.

Comment: Try creating an [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem and posting that.

Comment: @David.Sparky: if your parsing code is not working, then please show it so someone can point out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > vecRestaurants;

std::ifstream in("restaurants.txt");
std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    std::vector<std::string> info;

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (std::getline(iss, line, '|'))
        info.push_back(line);

    vecRestaurants.push_back(info);
}

in.close();

// use vecRestaurants as needed...
```

With that said, assuming the meaning and order of the fields of each restaurant are always the same, you could alternatively define a `struct` to hold the individual fields and then create a `vector` of `struct` values instead, eg:

```
struct sRestaurantInfo
{
    std::string name;
    float field2; // ie 42.74, what is this?
    float field3; // ie -73.69, what is this?
    std::string address;
    std::string url;
    std::string type;
    // what are the remaining numbers?
};

std::vector<sRestaurantInfo> vecRestaurants;

std::ifstream in("restaurants.txt");
std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    sRestaurantInfo info;

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::getline(iss, info.name, '|');
    std::getline(iss, line, '|'); std::istringstream(line) >> info.field2;
    std::getline(iss, line, '|'); std::istringstream(line) >> info.field3;
    std::getline(iss, info.address, '|');
    std::getline(iss, info.url, '|');
    std::getline(iss, info.type, '|');
    // read the remaining numbers if needed...

    vecRestaurants.push_back(info);
}

in.close();

// use vecRestaurants as needed...
```

Comment: @Chiel Not homework. I'm redoing some of my python code in C++ in preparation for next semester when I will be taking a C++ class with completely different assignments.